# Getting value of TextBlock inside AutoCompleteBox DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, autocompletebox

How do I get the value of a TextBlock inside an WPF AutoCompleteBox container within a DataTemplate?

Below is my AutoCompleteBox XAML

```
<my:AutoCompleteBox  Name="acLastName"
    FilterMode="StartsWith"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionChanged='acLastName_SelectionChanged'
    ValueMemberPath="LastName">
        <my:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name='UserDetails'>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name='UserId' Text="{Binding UserDetailsId}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserId}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comapany}" />
                </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
        </my:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</my:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

`acLastName.SelectedItem` will be your UserDetails object.

So cast that puppy up and access UserDetailsId through that:

```
((UserDetails)acLastName.SelectedItem).UserDetailsId
```